# Increase width of tab bar item to fit image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I am doing  a simple tab based app, with one 2 tab items and I would like to have an image in 
each tab.

The problem is, tabbarcontroller is cropping the images rather than fitting them in. I just have two images, basically text, saying "ABOUT","SETTINGS" and i would like them to take the full width of the tab bar. Something like the attached image. How can i achieve this without the images getting cropped.

Referring to the image "ABOUT" & "SCAN QR" are images.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you wish to accomplish is achievable by using the standard controls.
I'd recommend using a custom toolbar instead of the tab bar controller.

Comment: Yeah i guess, what i am doing for now is hide the tabbar and overlay it with custom buttons